# How can I add data accessors to an existing property in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, oop, object, getter-setter

Suppose I have an Object like so:

```
var foo = {
   baz: 'some primitive type'
}
```

Is there any way to add getters and setters to foo.baz?

Comment: getter -> `foo.baz` and setter -> `foo.baz = 'new string'`

Comment: What should these accessors do? Don't you like `foo.baz` as a getter?

Comment: `foo = { get baz() { }, set baz() { } }`

Answer (score 3):

You can redefine the property:

```
Object.defineProperty(foo, "baz", {
  value: foo.baz,
  get: function() { return "no baz for you"; },
  set: function(value) { whatever(value); }
});
```

JavaScript getters and setters are tricky to use because the property cannot be accessed as a simple property. All accesses, setting and getting, go through the accessor functions, including accesses inside the functions themselves.

With Symbol property names (not yet widely available, unfortunately), it's pretty easy to make "shadow" properties where the real property value can be kept:

```
var bazShadow = Symbol("baz");
Object.defineProperties(foo, {
  [bazShadow]: { value: foo.baz },
  baz: {
    get: function() {
      return "baz value is " + this[bazShadow];
    },
    set: function(value) {
      this[bazShadow] = value;
    }
  }
});
```

The nature of Symbol instances is that they're guaranteed not to collide with anything when used as a property name. Failing that facility, you can use some convention to avoid name collisions; personally I use strings prefixed with "@" but one such hack is as good as another.

Comment: I think `Symbol` would be really useful. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add additional logic I'd capule the object like this:

```
function Foo(param) {
        // Private variable
        var _baz;
        // Getter
        this.getBaz = function(){
            return _baz;
        };
        // Setter
        this.setBaz = function(val){
            _baz = val;
        };
        // Public Sample
        this.publicBaz;
    }

    var myFoo = new Foo();
    myFoo.setBaz("Bar");
    console.log(myFoo.getBaz());
```

This allows you to have private variables, as well as public variables / functions. You could build your own getters and setters.
Each public accessible variable needs to have a "this."

Checkout this sample at JS Bin:
https://codepen.io/xremix/pen/YQbJoq/